# Multiple application under SSL (TCP 443)

Tags: ssl, networking, server, openfire, nat

I implemented a server with two deploy of different services(Apache and OpenFire).
And I want to implement https for my server, so my question is.
How to implement the SSL certificate on my server with two different application working with different ports?

I was looking about how to create a NAT network but I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache is an HTTP Server and for SSL by default HTTP Servers use 443 port.
However, Openfire in an XMPP Server and you can enable TLS in it which will by default use 5222 port. And for Openfire's admin application, HTTPS will be on 9091 port by default.

So you can have both servers on same machine with SSL enabled.

Comment: Do you means that if I have some services running on different ports I can setup SSL for each one and all my clients will connect to the server using mydomain.com:443 properly?

Comment: Yes, You can setup SSL on different services (installed on 1 server). And each service will use it's own port for secure connection. 443 port is for HTTPS connections. But Openfire never uses 443 port by default. So there will be no conflict. Simply put, just setup SSL in Apache and Openfire and if you face any issues, share here.

Comment: Thank you. I will try and let you know.